# How can i Join Two Alias table from Select Query

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in MSSQL I'm trying to JOIN two alias tables generated from SELECT Query Like this

```sql
SELECT COUNT(T1.A1) AS [count],T1.A2 AS [Cname] FROM (
SELECT A1.Column1,A1.Column2
FROM A1
) T1
GROUP By T1.A1
```

And I have Another Table Like

```sql
SELECT COUNT(T2.A2) AS [count],T2.A2 AS [Cname] FROM (
SELECT A2.Column1,A2.Column2
FROM A2
) T2
GROUP By T2.A2
```

I want result like this:

```
|   Cname  |T1.Count  | T2.Count |
|Column1   |   7      |  7       |
|Column2   |   9      |  7       |
```

I have tried with some JOIN but getting Invalid Object T1 .can any one suggest me how would i get my result table ,any small help appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried with joins and quote the error, both verbatim.

Comment: Your first query is not valid syntax as a standalone query - something you skippped. It also seems way overcomplicated but that is a guess since it is not valid. Derived table t1 has columns named Column1 and Column2 - you can't reference columns A1 or A2 in the outer query. Nor can you include A2 in the resultset without either adding it to the group by clause or using it with an aggregate. The derived table is a simple select - so there is no reason to use it at all - which is the overcomplicated aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `UNION ALL`?  Something like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(a.C2), a.C1
FROM (
SELECT A1.Column1 as C1, A1.Column2 as C2
FROM A1
UNION ALL 
SELECT A2.Column1 as C1, A2.Column2 as C2
FROM A2) a
GROUP BY a.C1
```